# UIPickerView scrolls in full screen - Swift

Tags: swift, scroll, uiscrollview, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

I have a question about my pickerview.
My page is a UIScrollView. How to scroll my pickerview from any part of my page?

My pickerview is this:

```
//Create a frame (placeholder/wrapper) for the picker and then create the picker
    let picker: UIPickerView = {
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 230, y: -150, width: 80, height: 300));

        picker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return picker
    }()

    //set the pickers datasource and delegate

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // returns number of rows
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return 5;
    }

    // Return the title of each row in your picker
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print(row)
        return "\(row)"
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }
```

Comment: The picker view you created from your code, is it not on your specified location x 230 y -150?

Comment: no, the location is right but when I scroll with my finger in any part of my screen I would scroll my picker

Comment: Ok. You wants your picker to always pinned at that location and never disappear? Or you just want a picker to choose value for some of your text fields?

Comment: The first question is my question ;)

Comment: Okay. Why do you want to scroll your picker view from any part of your page? Then there is no way to scroll your scroll view, right?

Comment: I want to scroll my picker in any part of my page because in that moment my scroll view is stopped because my picker is in a alertcontroller.